# Prevent syslog() messages from going to journal daemon

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, rsyslog, systemd-journald

My application uses syslog() for generating logs that go into specific log files based on rules in rsyslog.conf.

Since migrating to Ubuntu 16.04, these logs have also started appearing in journalctl output and the system CPU utilisation of the machine has increased.

Is there a way to disable these syslog messages from going to journal daemon?

Thanks!